# restore Thunderbird backup in Outlook 2013

Tags: thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is there a way to restore a backup of a Thunderbird account, created with MozBackup, **without** using third party tools?

Or just copying the mails?

I've used Thunderbird for almost 10 years, but now I want to use Outlook for several reasons and I don't want to lose all my mails.

Comment: And what, exactly, is keeping you from using Thunderbird to export these mails in a format Outlook understands?

Comment: All sites and articels I found say, that there is no way to export mails in .pst format, without using tools or something else.

Answer (score 0):

No way without third-party tools (ironically, MozBackup is itself a third-party tool). MozBackup utilizes custom .pcv format for backups. Outlook can't read it. I recommend you to export your messages to EML and then you'll be able to import these messages using one of the many tools available, including freeware ones.